# excel: how to delete the contents of cell A if it equals cell B

Tags: excel

Am running Excel 2013 under Windows 7.

I have an Excel table that has 700,000+ rows. Columns A and B have identification codes.

For each row I have three scenarios: 1) ID code is in cell A; 2) ID code is in cell B; 3) ID code is in cell A and cell B.

For scenario #3, I want to delete the contents of cell A - in effect, removing the duplicate value in cell A.

Once that is done, I'll combine Columns A and B into a single Column of identification codes (which I know how to do).

Please help me code this statement:

For each row where the value in cell A = the value in cell B, delete the value in cell A.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using a database for this?

Comment: In scenarios #1 and #2 and the cells without ID code blank?

Comment: If there is no simple Excel solution, my next step would be to export the table as a text file and use GNU awk. Hoping to be able to do this inline with excel

Comment: Yes, in scenarios 1 and 2, the cell that does not have an ID is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cells are blank in scenarios #1 and #2 (where there are no IDs), you could add a column C and put the formula:

```
=IF(A1="",B1,A1)
```

And fill down the rows. Copy/Paste Values the column C, and delete columns A and B altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- create a new column wherever you want.
- put this formula in your new column `=A2=B2`, considering the first
  row probably is the headers
- extend the formular to all the rows
- add an auto filter to your whole sheet (From the Data menu, select Filter, from the submenu, select AutoFilter)
- filter the `TRUE` results in your new column

You can now select the values in column A and delete them.